# Sequelize stalls mocha

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, sequelize.js

I am trying to test my routes and my controllers.  Here is a demo test that I wrote to see if everything is working properly.

```html
import chai from "chai";
import chaiHttp from "chai-http";
import chaiAsPromised from "chai-as-promised";
import sinon from "sinon";
import sinonChai from "sinon-chai";
import wtfnode from "wtfnode";
import UserRepo from "../repositories/userRepository";
import server, { stopServer } from "../app";
import db from "../models/index";

wtfnode.init();

chai.use(chaiHttp);
chai.use(chaiAsPromised);
chai.use(sinonChai);
chai.should();

describe("TEST", () => {
  describe("Happy Path", () => {
    before(() => {
      sinon.stub(UserRepo, "getUsers");
      const users = [
        { id: 1, first_name: "test", last_name: "test" },
        { id: 2, first_name: "test", last_name: "test" },
        { id: 3, first_name: "test", last_name: "test" },
        { id: 4, first_name: "test", last_name: "test" },
        { id: 5, first_name: "test", last_name: "test" }
      ];
      UserRepo.getUsers.returns(users);
    });
    it("Retrieves users from the database and renders an index page displaying all the users", done => {
      chai
        .request(server)
        .get("/admins/users")
        .end((err, res) => {
          res.should.have.status(200);
          UserRepo.getUsers.should.have.been.calledOnce;
          done();
        });
    });
    after(() => {
      UserRepo.getUsers.restore();
      stopServer();
      db.sequelize.close();
      wtfnode.dump();
    });
  });
});
```

And the snippet below shows how I am exporting the server in my "app.js"

```html
const server = app.listen(port, () => {
  /* eslint-disable no-console */
  console.log(`App Running on port ${port}`);
  /* eslint-enable no-console */
});

export const stopServer = () => {
  console.log("Shutting the server");
  server.close();
};

export default server;
```

Although I am trying to shut the server down and close the database connection, mocha does not exit properly

So I included wtfnode to see which processes keep mocha from exiting gracefully. wtfnode report is shown below:

```html
[WTF Node?] open handles:
- File descriptors: (note: stdio always exists)
  - fd 1 (tty) (stdio)
  - fd 2 (tty) (stdio)
- Sockets:
  - (?:?) -> null:? (destroyed)
  - IP ADDRESS:52510 -> IP ADDRESS:3306
- Timers:
Unable to determine callsite for "bound". Did you require `wtfnode` at the top of your entry point?
  - (10000 ~ 10 s) bound  @ unknown:0
  - (10000 ~ 10 s) (anonymous) @ C:\GVW6\node_modules\generic-pool\lib\Pool.js:389
  - (9999 ~ 9 s) bound @ C:\GVW6\node_modules\generic-pool\lib\ResourceRequest.js:48
```

From what I understand the process running on port 3306 is preventing mocha from exiting, and the port 3306 is my database server.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Why are you making the callback to the `after` function in your test `async`?

Comment: i think db.sequelize.close() returns a promise, and maybe thats preventing mocha to properly close

Comment: Based on what @ArielAlvarado said, if you keep `async` in you can use `await` to force the promise to resolve:
`await db.sequelize.close();`

Comment: @dpopp07 I forgot to delete that, was trying something.  Will edit it out

Comment: @dpopp07 I deleted the "async".  Still getting the same result and the wtfnode report is the same

Comment: Keep async and add await before db.sequelize.close()

Comment: @ArielAlvarado I tried awaiting close(), did not work, still the same result

Comment: Have you tried commenting out `db.sequelize.close();` ? I've seen `mocha` behave like this when the server doesn't close properly, the database can keep on running but if the server stops, that should be all that the `mocha` process is tied to

Comment: @dpopp07 Please see my last answer, thanks for all the help though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was another script in the application that was instantiating sequelize.  That script was not closing the connection.  Added close commands there and resolved the problem.  Thanks everyone for helping out :)